# CSS3 Transition Out Custom Animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a custom animation in CSS3 which I can transition into view, but I cannot transition it out. Take a look at my Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/SW8Ly/. Note that this transition is only working in Webkit browsers as of now.

Try rolling your mouse over the styled text input. The background transitions from white into a blueish color when you roll your mouse over the text field, but it does not transition from blue to white.

I thought the `ease-in-out` property would take care of this, but it appears only to do so for pre-defined animations.

How can I transition from blue to white on mouse out?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the default (-webkit-)transition method? Doesn't seem you want to do something strange at all. Just look to this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/savver/SW8Ly/2/

See this for the effects: http://www.css3.info/preview/css3-transitions/ Just scroll down and you'll see what every property does.

Comment: Ah... wow, that's simple! Will this work for -o-, -ms-, -moz- as well?

Comment: Never mind, I just saw where browser support for this idea was mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: Yes it will. The -ms- won't work yet, at least not in IE7-IE9. IE10 might support it. Opera, Firefox and the webkit browsers does support it.

Comment: No problem! IE10 beta does support the transition property.